# Store long number in MS access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

How can I store 12 character long number in MS Access 2016, if the field cannot be empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following solution:(`Is Null Or Not Like "*[!0-9]*"`):

[image]